# App crashes on startup, only on my computer

Tags: ios, debugging, uiapplication

I have Xcode 6.1.1, and my app crashes on start up. It never reaches the start view (not even its awakeFromNib), but crashes on UIApplication on main. When it breaks there, I get NOTHING in the debug. Literally nothing. If I continue the program anyways it will work, flawlessly. But it ALWAYS breaks at UIApplication at startup. So I press "continue" and the app works as intended. I've tried the project on another computer, works fine there. I've tried reclone my project, doesn't work on my computer/xcode, but on another computer. It's just as if I have a breakpoint on UIApplication main...

If I reverse to previous commits, like 18 commits back, it works fine. If I then remerge with latest commit, it crashes on UIApplication again.

Starting to get upset here, anyone who has the faintest idea of what could be wrong here?

Comment: Sometimes you have to clear the solution, and delete all the local file. I add problems like this. We have to clear the xcode cache and simulator. Maybe try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

- remove all breakpoints.
- make sure you are not sharing breakpoints
  in repository ;), check your git ignore file if needed, check data in
  git.
- add exception break point to all Objective-C Exceptions
- run the project

Answer (score 0):

Found it. The problem was that there was a breakpoint set on "All exceptions" in the breakpoint data. It felt so weird that I could force to continue and it would work flawlessly, so it was indeed a breakpoint sneaking about.

Thanks for the help, I would not have found this without your help.